# How can I change action class entry in struts.xml dynamically?

Tags: struts2

I have an application where I want to modify(or overwrite) action mapping in struts.xml with new entry.
For detailed explanation here is the scenario.

In my application I have different stages like registration, change_data, I am managing these using `context Param`.

Web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <description>Current stage of the application</description>
    <param-name>stage</param-name>
    <param-value>registration</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I have an action which is redirect request for Payment Gateway i.e payment  gateway is sending user to this action.

struts2.xml (demo entries)

```
<!-- for registration -->
<action name="paymentResponse" class="abc.xyz.PaymentResponse">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">paymentForReg.tiles</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">home.tiles</result>
</action> 

<!-- for change data -->
<action name="paymentResponse" class="abc.xyz.PaymentResponseForChangeData">
    <result name="input" type="tiles">paymentForChangeData.tiles</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">home.tiles</result>
</action>
```

So when stage of the application changes, what I am doing is changes stage in `web.xml` and commenting one entry from of action from `struts.xml`

So to summarize I have multiple actions with same name and I want to trigger(or change class name of action) action on the basis of `context param`. is there any way to do it?

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

Comment: Wildcard won't work because I want to change `action class`, `action Name` has to be same. Whereas wildcard work on the basis of `actionName`

Comment: Since in Struts2 action classes are hidden, and action names are exposed, and this is wanted, then your requirements smell a lot of XY problem

Comment: isn't there any way to put conditional statement in struts.xml or change these entries programmatically on context startup

Comment: What you are saying is: *I don't want to walk for 1km forward; is there a way to move the earth 1km backwards ?* It doesn't make sense. It's XY, believe me. You are looking for a techical fix to your SOLUTION, but the solution itself is wrong, you should step back up to the problem, and find a logical fix for the problem, a new solution. Then looking for the technical way to implement it. My 2 cents, feel free to zoom out and describe your (real) problem agnostically by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong i think you have to use dynamic action like below then you can use the same action and same entry in xml

struts.xml:

```
<action name="paymentResponse" class="abc.xyz.RedirectPaymentResponse" method="updateCriteria">
        <result name="response" type="tiles">paymentForChangeData.tiles</result>
        <result name="responsechanged" type="tiles">paymentForReg.tiles</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">home.tiles</result>
</action>
```

Action class:

```
public class RedirectPaymentResponse extends AbstractAppAction {


        public String execute () throws Exception
        {
            // some code
            return "success";
        }

        public String updateCriteria(){

            //logic here

            if(PaymentResponse){
            // code here
            return "response";

            }

            if(PaymentResponseChanged){
            // code here
            return "responsechanged"

            }

}
```